# Funcion para imprimir

Tags: php, javascript

le agregué un botón "Imprimir" a mi vista :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quería saber si existe alguna forma, ya sea en PHP o JS, que al hacer click en ese botón, me mande a esta pantalla (que es la que se abre cuando apretamos CTRL+P)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

gracias y saludos!

Comment: al margen de tu pregunta, veo que tienes varias preguntas publicadas, pero practicamente ninguna calificada o aceptada (que es dando clic en la palomita del lado izquierdo) ; por favor revisa y comienza a calificar los aportes, de otro modo la comunidad podría pensarlo antes de seguir comentando pues no indicas si de todos esos aportes alguno te ha servido, considera que hay personas que invertido tiempo en apoyarte por lo cual dedica unos minutos a lo que te digo

Comment: perdon, es que soy nuevo, no lo hice aproposito, sino es que no se bien como funciona la pagina.. pero ahora haré lo que me dijiste.. gracias

Comment: no te preocupes, se que no lo haces a propósito; dale una vuelta por aqui que es parte del centro de ayuda y te indica como proceder https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A través de Javascript puedes utilizar la siguiente función:

```
window.print();
```

Y colocarla en la acción del botón que deseas que imprima.

Comment: muchas gracias nuevamente!